# Assign value to nested viewmodel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nested, viewmodel

I am a bit new to MVC, and have some difficulties assigning value/data to nested viewmodels. When I run the application the nested views does not show any content, but when I debug the controller the values are set. 
Do nested viewmodels have to be instantiated in a constructor in the main viewmodel? How?

I did get it to work with models instead og viewmodels, but i needed to add some validation.

Example:

```
public class MainViewModel
{ 
public NestedViewModel NestedViewModel { get; set; }
} 
public class NestedViewModel
{
public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

And in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Main()
{
var mvm = new MainViewModel();
mvm.NestedViewModel = new NestedViewModel();
mvm.NestedViewModel.Name = data.Name.ToString();
return View(mvm);
}
```

And in the view:

```
@model WEB.Models.MainViewModel
@{Html.RenderPartial("_NestedView", Model.NestedViewModel);}
```

And nested view:

```
@model WEB.Models.MainViewModel
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NestedViewModel.Name)
```

The textbox does not have any content, whereas the controller has.

Comment: Your not returning the model to the view - `return View(mvm);` (and you have not set the value of `NestedViewModel` so the code you have shown would throw an exception anyway)

Comment: Stephen is right, the compiler wouldn't let you build this example. For the models issue, in the nested view you ad using "MainViewModel", but in the RenderPartial you give NestedViewModel as parameter. Then in you use it as a MainViewModel in the TextBoxFor function... Either you give a MainViewModel as parameter or change the using in you nested view and use the parameter as NestedViewModel

Comment: Your edit has corrected some issues but will still throw an exception. Your partial expects `MainViewModel` but your passing it `NestedViewModel`

Comment: Yes, thanks. But what do you mean that I have not set the value of NestedViewModel? Doesn't this set the value: mvm.NestedViewModel.Name = data.Name.ToString();

Comment: NestedViewModel only has model.Name

Comment: @user3082768, Yes,  now that you have edited your question it does :). But your code will now throw another exception. Post your **real** code!

Comment: I am passing the property NestedViewModel in the MainViewModel, not the actual NestedViewModel, and I do not get any exceptions

Comment: You are getting an exception with the code you have shown (unless `NestedViewModel` is `null`), and the fact that you accepted the answer you did proves it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@model WEB.Models.MainViewModel
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NestedViewModel.Name)

//should be

@model WEB.Models.NestedViewModel
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
```